# How to close console in Void Bastards?

Tags: keyboard, void-bastards

While playing *Void Bastards*, I somehow opened up a command line console. I could not figure out how to close the console, so I was just stuck at the command line unable to play. The keyboard settings in the options menu do not list anything like a console. Unfortunately I typed "exit", which closed the game.

**How can I close the developer console and go back to the game?** (Also how did I open it in the first place?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/857980/discussions/1/1638662230367178620/), it's <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> to toggle the dev console

(That's a tilde)